# How to display sort icon when the page loading

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I used bootstrap 3 for my project, I used table sort icon i faced some conflict on this sorting icon, when the page loading sort icon are not displayed, when i click on the table header display the sort icon ,

Please help me to fix this issue,
how to display sort icon when the page loading

this is my code

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="corporate" class="table table-bordered report-table " style="width:100%">
                      <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th  style="width:200px;" (click)="coporateCustomerSortBy('name')">
                          <div class="disp-blk-2"> Name    <span *ngIf="sortType == 'name' && !sortReverse" class="fas fa-sort-amount-up"></span>
                            <span *ngIf="sortType == 'name' && sortReverse" class="fas fa-sort-amount-down"></span></div>

                        </th>
                        <th style="width:200px;" (click)="coporateCustomerSortBy('location')">
                          <div class="disp-blk-2" >Location <span *ngIf="sortType == 'location' && !sortReverse" class="fas fa-sort-amount-up"></span>
                            <span *ngIf="sortType == 'location' && sortReverse" class="fas fa-sort-amount-down"></span></div>

                        </th>
                        <th style="width:200px;" (click)="coporateCustomerSortBy('website')">
                          <div class="disp-blk-2">Website   <span *ngIf="sortType == 'website' && !sortReverse" class="fas fa-sort-amount-up"></span>
                            <span *ngIf="sortType == 'website' && sortReverse" class="fas fa-sort-amount-down"></span></div>

                        </th>
                        <th style="width:200px;">
                          <div class="disp-blk-2">Phone Number</div>
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:200px;">
                          <div class="disp-blk-2">No. of Facilities</div>
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:200px;" (click)="coporateCustomerSortBy('venue')">
                          <div class="disp-blk-2">Venue Name  <span *ngIf="sortType == 'venue' && !sortReverse" class="fas fa-sort-amount-up"></span>
                            <span *ngIf="sortType == 'venue' && sortReverse" class="fas fa-sort-amount-down"></span></div>

                        </th>

                        <th style="width:200px;">
                          <div class="disp-blk-2">Options</div>
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `fas` class be `fa`?

Comment: @AndreasFurster Sir, Icon is working fine, when I click the table header icon is display, I want to show it page loading,User can to find there is available the  sorting option